# How to find which admin logged in django admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I have extended django admin User using OnetoOne Relation,

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    USER_TYPE = ( 
                (2, 'SUPER ADMIN'),
                (1, 'ADMIN'),
                (0, 'USER'),
                )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', unique=False)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(u'User Type',max_length=1,choices=USER_TYPE,blank=False)
```

I want do this.

I donno how can I use that loggedin user type variable below,
I defined User type in OneToOne relation to django User.
I want to find whether the logged in user is admin with loggedin_user_type == 1 or not.

```
loggedin_user_type = request.User(something here ) 
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    if not logged_in_user_type :
         logged_in_user_type ==2 
    if logged_in_user_type ==  1  :
        USER_TYPE = ( 
                (1, 'ADMIN'),
                (0, 'USER'),
                 )
    else :     
       logged_in_user_type = ( 
               (2, 'SUPER ADMIN'),
               (1, 'ADMIN'),
               (0, 'USER'),
            )
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', unique=False)
user_type = models.IntegerField(u'User Type',max_length=1,choices=USER_TYPE,blank=False)

   Show other type of model
```

Comment: What are you trying to do besides checking that the user is admin?

Comment: @dan-klasson Thanks I improved the question

Comment: I still don't understand what it is you are trying to do. Django already has ways to check whether the user is logged in and or is admin. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @dan-klasson different users will login to the admin site with different user ids, I want to show differnt models ( only changing options ) with different user type values

Comment: Then you should have a look at Django Admin's Group permissions. No coding required.

Comment: @dan-klasson finally got answer,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [formfield for choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formf)  One can do this

```
def formfield_for_choice_field(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "user_type":
        kwargs['choices'] = ( 
            (1, 'ADMIN'),
            (0, 'USER'),
            )

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs['choices'] += ((2, 'SUPER ADMIN'),)
    return super(UserProfileAdmin, self).formfield_for_choice_field(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```